# CodeIgniter 4 error: Class "App\Filters\FilterJwt" not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to make a JWT Filter with CI4. But when I set my filter in the `app/Config/Filter.php` file, it always throws an error although it is definitely in the `app/Filters/` directory.

```
Class "App\Filters\FilterJwt" not found
```

I've been trying to create a new directory in the `app` path and named it `AuthFilter` but in vain.

`/Config/Filter.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use App\Filters\FilterJwt;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\InvalidChars;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\SecureHeaders;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * Configures aliases for Filter classes to
     * make reading things nicer and simpler.
     */
    public array $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'authentication' => FilterJwt::class

    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that are always
     * applied before and after every request.
     */
    public array $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'csrf',
            // 'invalidchars',
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that works on a
     * particular HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).
     *
     * Example:
     * 'post' => ['foo', 'bar']
     *
     * If you use this, you should disable auto-routing because auto-routing
     * permits any HTTP method to access a controller. Accessing the controller
     * with a method you don’t expect could bypass the filter.
     */
    public array $methods = [];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that should run on any
     * before or after URI patterns.
     *
     * Example:
     * 'isLoggedIn' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
     * @var array
     */
    public $filters = [
        'authentication' => [
            'before' => [
                'users/*',
                'users'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

`/App/Filters/FilterJwt.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use Exeption;

class MyFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    use ResponseTrait;
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $header = $request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
        try {
            helper('jwt');
            $encodedToken = getJwt($header);
            checkJWT($encodedToken);
            return $request;
        } catch (Exeption $e) {
            return Services::response()->setJson([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ])->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Proof that the file is in the directory:

[image: /App/Filters/FilterJwt.php]

CI4 error:

[image: CI4 Class not Found]

As you can see, the CI4 framework can't find the "Filters" folder although it's right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Rename your class from "MyFilter" to "FilterJwt".*

Instead of:❌

**/App/Filters/FilterJwt.php**

```php
class MyFilter implements FilterInterface
{
//...
```

Use this:✅

**/App/Filters/FilterJwt.php**

```php
class FilterJwt implements FilterInterface
{
//...
```

Comment: Ahhhhh didn't realize I haven't rename the class